# Does it make no sense to have a external resource dll in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resource-management

I have been trying to find recommended practices for resource management in the ASP.NET MVC app.. (target .NET 4.0 )

so far I have not been able to figure out whether should I add a separate satellite assembly to my MVC app or add the resources in the project itself.

Also the satellite assembly creation is quite different in MVC Apps. Perhaps they are not even called as satellite assemblies.. What I understood is that in order to refer to an external resource.dll file, I should create a different ASP.NET MVC prjoect, add my resource files to the "Resources" folder and then add references to the dlls thus generated. Is this the correct way? The al.exe process is I believe not relevant for MVC apps.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can't you store all the resource classes in a separate class library? That's what i'm doing in my current project

Comment: @Mark: Seems like a good idea..

Comment: @ShaiCohen: I want to bundle all the resources in a separate component. I have a separate component that does the localization (its an independent component that loads the resource files and returns teh translated strings).. Hence the resource files should be bundled in such a way that the localization component and the ASP.NET WEb app both can load them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bundled these resources in a separate dll as per Mark and this seems to work fine..